# MVC 3 EditorTemplates not working on production

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, editortemplates

I'm facing a strange problem when deploying my application to the production server.

I've used the Editor Templates to create date pickers (add class to date box and let jquery show the date picker).

This is working perfect on development where I'm running the site on a local IIS 7 webserver (not the development IIS express)
When I've deployed the application to the production machine, the date boxes are showed as regular text boxes instead of the date picker.

Is there something that I can check that's not on the production machine that can cause these kind of problems?

The DateTime.cshtml in the Views\Shared\EditorTemplates folder:

```
@model DateTime?
@Html.TextBox("", (Model.HasValue ? Model.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty), new { @class = "datePicker" })
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thx

Comment: JQuery is definitely loaded on the prod environment? doing alert($); gives you something?

Comment: Jquery is loaded. But it's not jquery related. The input hasn't received the class "datepicker" like set in the template. If I add manually an input with  the class datepicker, it works fine.

Comment: ok - adding some fudd text to that template shows up when you do EditorFor(x=>x.DateTimeProperty) ?

Comment: No, not even that. I've tried to add some test data in the template but that's not showing aether. It's like he doesn't recognise it's a DateTime field. Funny he's doing it well on development.  Could this be depending on the version of MVC 3 Dll's?

Comment: i'd remove all files from prod and try to redeploy if i were you. sometimes stuff goes missing in the move. or you could just check the template is there on prod? there's no UiHint on the property in the viewmodel is there?

Comment: In firebug, do you see any files that return a 404? Script files or css files?

Comment: Did a redeploy, not solved. @Bjorn, no 404's except for one image, not related to this problem. Hate those poblems.

Comment: I've been able to resolve the problem. I was using the deploy actions in VS2010. I've now deployed manually and moved all files to the webserver. This seems to be working. Afterwards I've removed all code files from the server and it keeps working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to resolve the problem. I was using the deploy actions in VS2010. I've now deployed manually and moved all files to the webserver. This seems to be working. Afterwards I've removed all code files from the server and it keeps working

Comment: I had the same problem and this is ridiculous! Just the EditorTemplate folder and contents aren't copied!!! How weird! Found another solution for this yet?

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this is a bit late but are you sure the "Build Action" on the file is set to "Content". We had the same problem and in our case it was set to "None".

Comment: Strange that it defaulted to that!  Solved my problem too.